# When a website is hit from two different browsers running on same computer. what are the properties that differ?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, tcp

Here they are hitting the same DNS and port. how does the client know those are two different browsers. And how does the client differentiate those connections?

I heard this question from one of my friends and was asked this in an interview, felt interesting to me, can someone outline few differences.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. The client doesn't care. Anything stateful will be via something like a session ID in a cookie.

Comment: Well, there is state in the TCP connection. The source port for each browser is different.

Answer (score 1):

The source port for each browser's TCP connection(s) is/are different.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s01.html

> A TCP connection is distinguished by four values:

```
<source-IP-address, source-port, destination-IP-address, destination-port>
```

> Together, these four values uniquely define a connection. Two
> different TCP connections are not allowed to have the same values for
> all four address components

Comment: Technically correct, but also useless: a single browser opening a single site will create MANY different connections (usually mapped to different elements on the web page and thus distinct HTTP GET requests). The difference in TCP source port doesn't have any relationship with the difference in source process.

Comment: But, each of those outbound connections (and distinct ports) is associated with the process of the browser that made the connection, so the OS knows which process gets the answer from the webserver. OP is asking how does the client know which response from the server goes to which browser, and it's the TCP connection tuple - and the only thing distinct in this scenario between browsers is the source port.
If that's not the answer, what is?

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s01.html
`. A TCP connection is distinguished by four values:
<source-IP-address, source-port, destination-IP-address, destination-port>
Together, these four values uniquely define a connection. Two different TCP connections are not allowed to have the same values for all four address components`

Comment: i heard they were referring to something about fml port

Comment: @mfinni so,  same personal computer, same browser, hitting the same website from two different tabs only differ in port number from clients view, that's what you say right?

Comment: If it's in the same browser with different tabs, presumably the browser is tracking which thread is making which TCP connection. Regardless, the answer is unique TCP connections.

Comment: @mfinni what about fml ports, do they have any relation with these source ports? just curious

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119868/discussion-between-linux-trainee-and-mfinni).

Comment: @Massimo "a single browser opening a single site will create MANY different connections" NO, not necessarily. With HTTP/2 there are streams inside a single TCP/IP connection hence allowing multiplexing.

Comment: HTTP has been stateless for many years. To be able to identify clients, applications started to issue cookies, and clients are expected to show the cookie on every subsequent request. So if the server discovers a cookie-less connection if can consider this a 'first encounter' and set the cookie. Given that the value of the cookie is unique it can be used as a session id. Other values of the two browsers' requests are not necessarily different.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek of course. My point is simply that there is no one-to-one relationship between a process and a TCP connection. Different connections can identify different processes, but they could as well be made from the same process (and let's not even start about threads).

Comment: @Massimo "no one-to-one relationship between a process and a TCP connection. " You think? Strange then that `netstat` is able to show one line per connection and the process owning it (a given process can have multiple connections of course both incoming and outgoing). Only one process can handle a given (established) connection.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek never argued against that. But connections are opened and closed very frequently, whenever a browser needs to GET something from a web site, often repeatedly and continuously while you are just looking at the page or scrolling down it. Truly, no two processes can share the same connection; but a process can definitely open several ones to the same destination.